# Django Localhost Redirecting too many times

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-allauth

Hi there I created a decorator to protect a certain view from unauthorized persons though I am using django allauth to handle my authentications so I've used its login url. On testing whether the authorization works instead of redirecting me to the login page Localhost gets stuck in a redirect loop
here is a look at my code

decorators.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test


def seller_required(function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url='account_login'):
    '''
    Decorator for views that checks that the logged in user is a seller,
    redirects to the log-in page if necessary.
    '''
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        lambda u: u.is_active and u.is_seller,
        login_url=login_url,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
    )
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    return actual_decorator
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView,DetailView, ListView
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .decorators import seller_required


@method_decorator( seller_required , name='dispatch')
class SellerDashBoardView(ListView):
    model = Seller
    template_name = 'seller_dashboard.html'
```

App level urls

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import SellerSignUpView, SellerDashBoardView

urlpatterns = [
    path('seller_reg/', SellerSignUpView.as_view(), name='seller_reg'),
    path('seller/', SellerDashBoardView.as_view(), name='seller_dash')
]
```

project level urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('user.urls')),
    #path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('store/', include('store.urls')),
    #path("djangorave/", include("djangorave.urls", namespace="djangorave")),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```